# Выбрать данные из трех таблиц MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Сделал тут запрос.

Работает т.к. надо, но только вот вопрос, почему он показывает два раза медучереждени 1. Как исправить?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68eb3b/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: localhost
-- Время создания: Сен 04 2015 г., 23:52
-- Версия сервера: 5.1.73-cll
-- Версия PHP: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `kamnedso_med`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `mp_gallery`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_gallery` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_hf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `mp_gallery`
--

INSERT INTO `mp_gallery` (`id`, `img`, `id_hf`) VALUES
(13, 'a946351740f6fa08143d5e91992e7bb2.png', 18),
(12, 'fd8042fd507849d1c9102d97459c53f5.jpg', 18);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `mp_health_facilities`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_health_facilities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `mp_health_facilities`
--

INSERT INTO `mp_health_facilities` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(20, 'Медучереждения 3'),
(19, 'Медучереждения 2'),
(18, 'Медучереждения 1');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `mp_health_facilities_boss_category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_health_facilities_boss_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `mp_health_facilities_boss_category`
--

INSERT INTO `mp_health_facilities_boss_category` (`id`, `title`, `alias`) VALUES
(1, 'Главная', 'glavnaya'),
(2, 'Для женщин', 'dlya_zhenshhin'),
(3, 'ДЛЯ ДЕТЕЙ', 'dlya_detej'),
(4, 'М/У ПО РАЙОНАМ', 'mu_po_rajonam'),
(5, 'Диагностика', 'diagnostika'),
(6, 'Прочие услуги', 'prochie_uslugi');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `mp_health_facilities_category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_health_facilities_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `mp_health_facilities_category`
--

INSERT INTO `mp_health_facilities_category` (`id`, `title`, `alias`, `id_category`) VALUES
(1, 'Больницы и стационары', 'bolnicy_i_stacionary', 1),
(2, 'Поликлиники', 'polikliniki', 1),
(3, 'Диспансеры', 'dispansery', 1),
(4, 'Медпункты и амбулатории', 'medpunkty_i_ambulatorii', 1),
(5, 'Травмпункты', 'travmpunkty', 1),
(6, 'Скорая помощь', 'skoraya_pomoshh', 1),
(7, 'Частные медцентры и клиники', 'chastnye_medcentry_i_kliniki', 1),
(8, 'Стоматология', 'stomatologiya', 1),
(9, 'Центры вакцинации', 'centry_vakcinacii', 1),
(10, 'Женские консультации', 'zhenskie_konsultacii', 2),
(11, 'Родильные дома', 'rodilnye_doma', 2),
(12, 'Центры планирования семьи и репродукции', 'centry_planirovaniya_semi_i_reprodukcii', 2),
(13, 'Детские больницы', 'detskie_bolnicy', 3),
(14, 'Детские поликлиники', 'detskie_polikliniki', 3),
(15, 'Детские медцентры', 'detskie_medcentry', 3),
(16, 'Стоматология', 'stomatologiya', 3),
(17, 'Травмпункты', 'travmpunkty', 3),
(18, 'Алатауский район', 'alatauskij_rajon', 4),
(19, 'Алмалинский район', 'almalinskij_rajon', 4),
(20, 'Ауэзовский район', 'auezovskij_rajon', 4),
(21, 'Бостандыкский район', 'bostandykskij_rajon', 4),
(22, 'Жетысуский район', 'zhetysuskij_rajon', 4),
(23, 'Медеуский район', 'medeuskij_rajon', 4),
(24, 'Турксибский район', 'turksibskij_rajon', 4),
(25, 'Диагностические центры', 'diagnosticheskie_centry', 5),
(26, 'Лаборатории и анализы', 'laboratorii_i_analizy', 5),
(27, 'Диагностика кожи и волос', 'diagnostika_kozhi_i_volos', 5),
(28, 'Ультразвуковые исследования (УЗИ)', 'ultrazvukovye_issledovaniya', 5),
(29, 'Магнитно-резонансная томография (МРТ)', 'magnitno-rezonansnaya_tomografiya', 5),
(30, 'Рентгенография', 'rentgenografiya', 5),
(31, 'Компьютерная томография (КТ)', 'kompyuternaya_tomografiya', 5),
(32, 'Эндоскопия', 'endoskopiya', 5),
(33, 'Маммография', 'mammografiya', 5),
(34, 'Функциональная диагностика (ЭКГ, ЭхоКГ, ЭЭГ, УЗДГ)', 'funkcionalnaya_diagnostika', 5),
(35, 'Санатории/дома отдыха', 'sanatoriidoma_otdyxa', 6),
(36, 'Клиники пластической хирургии и косметологии', 'kliniki_plasticheskoj_xirurgii_i_kosmetologii', 6),
(37, 'Производители мед. товаров', 'proizvoditeli_med_tovarov', 6),
(38, 'Наркологи', 'narkologi', 6),
(39, 'Мануальная терапия', 'manualnaya_terapiya', 6),
(40, 'Гомеопатия', 'gomeopatiya', 6),
(41, 'Психологические центры и службы', 'psixologicheskie_centry_i_sluzhby', 6),
(42, 'Лечение за рубежом', 'lechenie_za_rubezhom', 6),
(43, 'НЕТРАДИЦИОННАЯ МЕДЕЦИНА', 'netradicionnaya_medecina', 6),
(44, 'МАССАЖ', 'massazh', 6),
(45, 'ДЕТСКИЙ МАССАЖ', 'detskij_massazh', 6);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `mp_link_health_facilities_and_category`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_link_health_facilities_and_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_health_facilities` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `mp_link_health_facilities_and_category`
--

INSERT INTO `mp_link_health_facilities_and_category` (`id`, `id_health_facilities`, `id_category`) VALUES
(13, 18, 14),
(14, 18, 41),
(12, 18, 13),
(11, 18, 3),
(10, 18, 2),
(9, 18, 1),
(15, 18, 42),
(16, 19, 13),
(17, 19, 14),
(18, 19, 15),
(19, 20, 10),
(20, 20, 11);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT hf.title as hf_title,hf.id as hf_id, c.title as c_title, g.img
FROM mp_health_facilities hf 
LEFT JOIN mp_link_health_facilities_and_category l ON l.id_health_facilities = hf.id
LEFT JOIN mp_health_facilities_category c ON l.id_category = c.id
LEFT JOIN mp_gallery g ON g.id_hf = hf.id
WHERE l.id_category=13
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68eb3b/3/0)**:

```
|            title | id |            title |                                  img |
|------------------|----|------------------|--------------------------------------|
| Медучереждения 1 | 18 | Детские больницы | a946351740f6fa08143d5e91992e7bb2.png |
| Медучереждения 1 | 18 | Детские больницы | fd8042fd507849d1c9102d97459c53f5.jpg |
| Медучереждения 2 | 19 | Детские больницы |                               (null) |
```

Comment: @alexander barakin у меня другой вопрос. Если я делаю по тому примеру то выходит куча списком с дублированием. А мне надо без дублирования

Comment: Простите, вот ссылка на код который сделал, вопрос сейчас исправлю! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68eb3b/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в вашем запросе два раза повторяется 18-е медучереждение из-за того, что для этого медучереждения у вас введено две записи в таблице `mp_gallery`:

```
INSERT INTO `mp_gallery` (`id`, `img`, `id_hf`) VALUES
(13, 'a946351740f6fa08143d5e91992e7bb2.png', 18),
(12, 'fd8042fd507849d1c9102d97459c53f5.jpg', 18);
```

чтобы избавиться от этого «дубля», уберите дублирование информации в таблице `mp_gallery`. либо придумайте критерии, по которым субд должна сделать выбор между этими двумя (равноценными) записями.

---

**обновление**

если критерий выбора одной из равноценных записей из таблицы `mp_gallery` вам не важен, то можете сделать группировку по идентификатору учреждения, добавив в конце вашего запроса:

```
group by hf.id
```

Comment: Спасибо! будем думать. Немного плаваю в теории по MySQL!

Comment: @duddeniska, без всякой теории, лишь методом «научного тыка» можно было убрать из запроса упоминания про таблицу `mp_gallery` и увидеть, что получившийся запрос возвращает нет три, а две записи.

Comment: На самом деле мне нужна галлерея, просто нужно что бы была первая попавшиеся запись, а не две! В таблицы галерея может быть больше одной записи к одному медучереждению

Comment: «возьми первую попавшуюся» — это для человека простой выбор, а для компьютера он значительно более «тяжёлый», нежели «возьми конкретно вот эту». так уж они устроены, эти компьютеры.

Comment: не имея представления о требованиях к логике вашей информационной системы, могу предложить на выбор: просто исключить дублирование; добавить столбец, в котором будет указано, какой **конкретно** из «дублей» надо использовать.

Comment: @duddeniska, я добавил обновление в ответ.

Comment: а групировка убирает дубли по определенному полю?

Comment: группировка, как следует из названия, группирует записи по указанному полю. я бы рекомендовал постараться выкроить время и почитать теоретическую литературу по реляционной модели данных. начинать можно с одноимённой википедийной статьи.